# Mosaico - how to 'insert' templates from a previous host?

Tags: mosaico

I'm moving hosts, and want to preserve a number of Mosaico templates that I've created. Mosaico had to be re-installed. It is running, but the templates are now gone. I have backups of the SQL tables. Attempts to just 'insert the rows' into civicrm_mosaico_template table have been unsuccessful. (and broke the mosaico install). So, uninstalled/reinstalled - to a clean mosaico again...

Any suggestions on how to re-import those templates?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you by any chance kept copies of the html source code for each template?  If you have then it would be easy to import them into new message templates in civicrm by copy and paste through the html editor for each new template by using the "Source" button

Comment: I don't see a 'source' button in the Mosaico Editor. (I do in the 'traditional template' editor though.)
I thought HTML was in the db in the mosaico template file, but, it's not clean. I do have html files, though they were the 'received' emails I sent to myself, so they'd need to have a bunch of cleanup so they could go out again. I'm beginning to think that is going to be my only recovery. Was hoping that it would go back into mosaico, vs std templates.

Comment: I dont have the Mosaico extension installed but I've successfully compiled a Mosaico template on the Mosaico website, copied the html and saved it in a new template in Administer/Communication/Message Templates/Add Message Template/HTML Format using the Source code therein.  If you already have the HTML code for the templates you wish to import then you could perhaps go down the route I've described.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It works the way peterb says. This means you have to design outside of CiviCRM but the procedure is quick.